# jquery select iframe children

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the editArea library and jquery to do what i need...

http://www.cdolivet.com/index.php?page=editArea&sess=2b8243f679e0d472397bfa959e1d3841

so in my html there is an iframe tag that editArea uses what i need is to access something like so with jquery

```
$('iframe textarea').keydown(function (e){
   number = 17; //any number really :)
    if(e.which == number){
        //do something...
        alert('Done...');
    }
});
```

I tried the above but it looks like it is not detecting that key. but it works if selector was $(document)
therefore the rest of the function works it's just it's not picking up the iframes textarea keydown

any ideas? 
Thanks

Comment: boys i know that it doesn't work but i only put that as a demostration ... but none of the answers are doing it for me.

I wonder if editArea has stopped the propagation or something of that kind?

Comment: Is the iframe pointing to the same domain as the parent page?

Comment: yes it is on the same domain it doesn't have a src attr `<iframe frameborder="0" name="frame_ettellCode" id="frame_ettellCode" style="border-width: 0px; overflow: hidden; display: inline; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>`

Answer (score 75, accepted):

```
$("iframe").contents().find("textarea").keydown(...)
```

Comment: Should note that .contents() only works if you are on the same domain

Comment: What if one isn't on the same domain? Can one still at least use an element clicked in that iframe to trigger something in the parent window?

Comment: Another syntax: $("textarea", $("iframe").contents()).keydown(...)

Comment: Also `.contents()` does not work if you're loading static html files on the browser.

Answer (score 9):

You need search within the inner `document` of the iframe, in order to get the `textarea` element:

```
var textarea = $('textarea', $('iframe').get(0).contentWindow.document);
textarea.keydown(function (e){
   var number = 17;
   var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);

    if(code == number){
        //do something...
        alert('Done...');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can travel any level, The above answers are correct. I did as below

```
var iframeMain = $("#iframe0").contents().find('#iframeMain');
var detailsForm = $(iframeMain).contents().find('#detailsform');
```

for accessing parents you can use

```
window.parent.parent. // upto any level
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to access the iframes `contentWindow.document`, not the iframe itself.

Comment: This worked like a charm. Example: use `document.querySelector('#test_frame').contentWindow.document` instead of just `document`. See [*HTMLIFrameElement.contentWindow - MDN web docs*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentWindow) for the detail.

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing

```
iframeDoc = document.getElementById('resultsFrame').contentWindow;
// result frame is id of iframe
$(iframeDoc).keydown(function(e))
{
// your functionality here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, I ended up getting the above to work by wrapping in this function:

```
$(window).blur(function () {
  // genius code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code helped me.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var iFrameDOM = $("iframe#frameID").contents();

iFrameDOM.find(".page").css("background-color", "#fff");
```

});