# Return value from simplemodal iframe popup to textbox on parent

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

I've have created a [simpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) popup. I want to return a value from a text input on the popup to a asp textbox on the parent page.

I have read all of the examples that are similar to this one, but none have answered my question.

My popup is a simple aspx page with a text input.
Here is the code:

#### JavaScript

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("a#lookup").click(function () {
      //Load the Lookup page as a modal popup..
      $.modal('<iframe src="TestPopup.aspx" height="200" width="450" style="border:5">', {
        onOpen: function (dialog) {
            dialog.overlay.fadeIn('slow', function () {
                dialog.container.slideDown('100', function () {
                    dialog.data.fadeIn('fast');
            }); 
          }); 
        },
        preventDefault: true,
        containerCss: {
          backgroundColor: "#fff",
          borderColor: "#aaa",
          height: 530,
          padding: 5,
          width: 880,
          escClose: false
        },
        closeHTML: "<a href='#'>Close</a>",
        appendTo: 'form',
        persist: true,
        overlayClose: true,
        onClose: function (dialog) {
          var result = dialog.data.find("#msgText").val();
          $('#txtLookupReturn').attr('value', result);
          dialog.data.fadeOut('200', function () {
            dialog.container.slideUp('200', function () {
              dialog.overlay.fadeOut('200', function () {
                $.modal.close();
              }); 
            });
          });
        }
      }); 
    });    
  });
```

#### TestPopup.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TestPopup.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebServicesTest.TestPopup" %> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">; 
<html xmlns="w3.org/1999/xhtml">; 
<head runat="server"> 
  <title></title> 
</head> 
<body> 
  <form id="form1" runat="server"> 
  <div> 
    <input id="msgText" type="text" value="I love jQuery!" /> 
  </div> 
  </form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

This is the line of code that is not working:

```
var result = dialog.data.find("#msgText").val();

$('#txtLookupReturn').attr('value', result);
```

When I try to grab the value of `#msgText`, I get no error and no value.
Appreciate any help!

Comment: Since your dialog is created as an iFrame with `TestPopup.aspx` as the URL, we can't tell what HTML is contained in your dialog, so we can't really debug your problem. Same for the variable `dialog`; you don't have the code that declares a `dialog` variable. You need to post an example that is simple and self-contained so that we can help you.

Comment: You also need to tell us what 'not working' means here: is it giving you an error in your console? (post the error message) Is it silently failing? Is it giving you garbage values?

Comment: <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TestPopup.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebServicesTest.TestPopup" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
 </head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input id="msgText" type="text" value="I love jQuery!" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: There is no error, just no value comes through.

Comment: I edited your question to include these comments.

Answer (score 2):

I think that your selection code should be this:

```
$("iframe[src='TestPopup.aspx']").contents().find("#msgText").val();
```

Selecting elements inside of iframes has some complexities which are addressed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893280/jquery-select-iframe-children) and [this blog post](http://seriouscoding.com/2009/05/22/how-to-access-an-iframe-with-jquery/).  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe) talks about permissions with JavaScript and iframes. I can't tell how your pages are organized, so I don't know if you will have problems with the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), but it's a good thing to read up on anyways.

#### Update

The more I look at your popup HTML, the more I think that you don't need to use an `iframe`. When I've used SimpleModal, I usually put my dialog HTML in an invisible `<div>`. The `iframe` will be unnecessarily slow and increase your server traffic. If you need to load values from the server, you might want to keep it as an `iframe`. If, however, you just need the user to provide values, include the dialog form as HTML on your page.

Comment: var result now returns as undefined.

Comment: @StephenLerch - Try `$("iframe[src='TestPopup.aspx']").contents().find("#msgText").val();`

Comment: @StephenLerch If this fixed your problem, please [accept my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).