# how to know if a DOM element is in the jquery scope?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jquery select iframe children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893280/jquery-select-iframe-children)

I have many frames in my asp.net website. Since I don't know its layout and I need to update a `<span>` value in a diferent diferent frame where my jquery code is, I do the following:

`$('#myspan').text('sometext');`

but anything changes. So I don't know if it's because jquery didn't manage to catch the element with this selector because is not in its scope or why.

However this:

`alert($('#myspan'));` it shows an alert with `[object][object]` as result.

Comment: `$(#'myspan')` looks wrong, you probably mean `$('#myspan')`

Comment: `alert($())` will also show `[object Object]` because `$()` always returns an object.

Comment: `alert($('#myspan'));` showing `[object Object]` does not mean it's matched an element. jQuery always returns an object whether it's matched something or not. If you do `alert($('#myspan').length);`, you'll probably see it's matched no elements.

Comment: I misspelled wrong. `$('#myspan')` updated!!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893280/jquery-select-iframe-children  for how to get elements within an `<iframe>`

Comment: Use a browser that has a good console (webkit) and use `console.log($('#myspan'));`. This is much better than alerting objects as strings.

Comment: Iambrinsreed, like this what is expected to be in the console if it works?

Comment: @a_maar you will actually see: `['<span id=""myspan'>...</span>']` in the console. saying it found 1 item with that id.

Comment: Matt I don't need to get element within `iframes` but within `frames` in the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jQuery function (`$('someSelector')`) will always return an object, even if no elements match the selector.

If you really are using multiple frames, you have a problem: jQuery can't find elements across frames, only in the current document/frame – unless you pass a proper context object for the specific document you want to target.

For example, if you have an `<iframe id="myframe">`, you can look for `#myspan` inside it with this:

```
var frameDoc = $('#myframe')[0].contentWindow.document;
var mySpan = $('#myspan', frameDoc);
```

For that to work, the iframe's source must be hosted in the same domain as the main page. There's also the following cleaner options, suggested in the comments below:

```
var mySpan = $("#myframe").contents().find('#myspan')
```

or

```
var mySpan = $('#myspan', $("#myframe").contents());
```

Comment: Does the context work across frames? What is the proper context - `iframe.document`?

Comment: @JanDvorak I suppose *yes* and *ifr.contentWindow.document*. Will test now to confirm.

Comment: @JanDvorak: The [SOP policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) ***will*** bite you here if your frames are on different domains.

Comment: @Matt even with CORS headers?

Comment: `var mySpan = $('#myspan', $("#myframe").contents());` is a little prettier.

Comment: @JanDvorak: AFAIK CORS permits x-domain requests, not x-domain DOM traversing. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460200/can-cross-origin-resource-sharing-headers-authorize-x-domain-iframe-access (and non of these approaches are well supported).

Comment: @JanDvorak Just to confirm: I tested, and it works (for the same domain, x-domain shouldn't work).

Comment: @iambriansreed jQuery `contents` docs even advocates `$("#myframe").contents().find('#myspan')`

Comment: @JanDvorak so not just prettier but recommended by the jQuery docs?

Comment: @iambriansreed not explicitly, but used in an example.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to debug jQuery problems is this pattern:

```
var e = $(...);
console.log(['Explanation', e.get()]);
```

`get()` without arguments will convert the strange jQuery selector result to a normal JavaScript array which you can expand in your browser's console. That should help to see what the selector returned.

If it doesn't match anything, then your selector is wrong somehow. Check the current DOM in your browser's development tools if the element is really there.