# How can I add an onclick event for all the iframes in a document with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a html with two iframes that change with a selector.

I would like to add an onclick event that triggers an url for some `<rect>` elements within the iframes.

I read the post [jquery select iframe children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893280/jquery-select-iframe-children) and I think the solution has to be quite similar.

However I am quite inexperienced in jquery and haven't been able to find it myself.

My trials so far have been the following:

```
$("#frame").content().("rect").click(function() {
window.alert("sometext");
});

$("frame").content().("rect").click(function() {
window.alert("sometext");
});

$("#frame").content().$("rect").click(function() {
window.alert("sometext");
});
```

Comment: what is `content().(rect)`? I guess you are missing `find`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss `find` as also commented by @Rakesh.

Though it depends on your html code as well, does the iframe has id `frame`? Then use `#frame` if it has class frame use `.frame`. If rect is an element just use `rect` like in below, if rect is an id use `#rect` and if rect is a classname use `.rect`.

```
$("#frame").contents().find("rect").click(function() {
    window.alert("sometext");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Indeed the issue was the find function. Also, after debugging a bit I found out I misspelled content() which should be contents().