# Get element class name inside of iframe by click on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

In briefly , I've an `iframe` that load form local HTML page and want to access this page's element `by click on them` ,such as `all type of inputs`, `dropdown list`, `table` and so on.
[image]

This is an HTML code that inside of iframe tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id="bootbody">
    <head>
        <title>test2</title>
        <link href='bootstrap.min.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' />
        <style>
            @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 0) {
            .panel {
            height: auto !important;
            }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body >
        <div id="testttt" class='container text-right'>
            <div class='row'>
                <div class='panel panel-default pull-right col-xs-12 col-sm-12' style='height:605px' id='16'>
                    <div class='panel-heading text-right row'>گروه 1</div>
                    <div class='panel-body'>
                        <div class='row'>
                            <div class='col-xs-12 pull-right col-sm-6' style='height:px' id='G1'>
                                <div class='row'>
                                    <div class='panel panel-default pull-right col-xs-12 col-sm-12' style='height:200px' id='12'>
                                        <div class='panel-heading text-right row'>گروه 2</div>
                                        <div class='panel-body'>
                                            <div class='row'>
                                                <div class='col-xs-12 pull-right col-sm-12' style='height:px' id='G1'>
                                                    <div class='row'>
                                                        <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-6 pull-right  text-right'>
                                                            <div class='row'>
                                                                <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-6 pull-right'><span>تکست 1</span></div>
                                                                <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-6'><input id='layout2' type='text' class='form-control form-control-sm' /></div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-6 pull-right  text-right'>
                                                            <div class='row'>
                                                                <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-6 pull-right'><span>عنوان</span></div>
                                                                <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-6'><input id='layout17' type='text' class='form-control form-control-sm' /></div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 pull-right text-right'>
                                                    <div class='row'>
                                                        <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-6 pull-right'><span>تکست 2</span></div>
                                                        <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-6'><input id='layout3' class='form-control form-control-sm' type='text' /></div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class='panel panel-default pull-right col-xs-12 col-sm-12' style='height:200px' id='13'>
                                        <div class='panel-heading text-right row'>گروه 3</div>
                                        <div class='panel-body'>
                                            <div class='row'>
                                                <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 pull-right text-right'><span>چک باکس 1</span><input id='layout7' type='checkbox'></input></div>
                                                <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 pull-right text-right'><span>چک باکس 2</span><input id='layout8' type='checkbox'></input></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class='col-xs-12 pull-right col-sm-6' style='height:NaNpx' id='G1'>
                                <div class='row'>
                                    <div class='panel panel-default pull-right col-xs-12 col-sm-12' style='height:200px' id='3'>
                                        <div class='panel-heading text-right row'>گروه</div>
                                        <div class='panel-body'>
                                            <div class='row'>
                                                <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12'>
                                                    <div class='row'>
                                                        <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-6 pull-right'><span>کومبو1</span></div>
                                                        <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-6'><select id='layout11' class='form-control form-control-sm'></select></div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12'><button style='height:30px;width:150px' id='btnUpdate_2' class='btn btn-default text-center'>ذخیره 2</button></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 pull-right text-right'>
                                        <div class='row'>
                                            <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-6 pull-right'><span>تکست 3</span></div>
                                            <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-6'><input id='layout12' class='form-control form-control-sm' type='text' /></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12'><button style='height:30px;width:150px' id='btnUpdate_1' class='btn btn-default text-center'>ذخیره 1</button></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and I load it into asp.net web form:

```
<div id="frameWrapper">
                    <iframe id="frame" src="../HtmlHolder/TEST2.html">[ممکن است بدلیل تنظیمات پیکر بندی مرورگرتان ،قادر به مشاهده ی نمایشگر موبایل نباشید.لطفا مرورگر خود را تغییر دهید.]
                    </iframe>
                </div>
```

this is script code to access element inside of iframe:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var frm = $("#frame").get(0);
            var doc = (frm.contentDocument ? frm.contentDocument : frm.contentWindow.document);//here is your document object
            var bdy = doc.body;
            alert(bdy);

        });
    </script>
```

I use above code to find iframe body, but can't access to it's element...

I google it but found other thing like `find element by class name` or find `specific element` that is not usage for me.
  How can I do it?
thank you so much.

```
NOTE: I read an HTML code from DB and then upload it into a folder on my host and then view it in ifram tag.
```

Comment: Post the code what you have tried?

Comment: you could try something like this `$('#iframe').contents().find("html").html();` then make it a jquery object and find the class

Comment: @JohnR , question is updated

Comment: @guradio, may i ask you to more explain or refer me to an article about it?

Comment: @HamidTalebi Share your `html` code too. Specifically content of `iframe`.

Comment: Are the iframe contents on the same domain?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery select iframe children](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893280/jquery-select-iframe-children)

Comment: In order to process click events if the iframe you may have to include that code in the iframe page content

Comment: @JohnR, i do it, do you have an idea? tnx

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss, yes, as i explained , i read it from one of my project folder

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss, NO ,IT IS NOT DUPLICATE WITH YOUR REFERENCE ,because in that question, he WANT TO FIND SPECIFIC ELEMENT, but here I WANT TO FIND ANY FORM ELEMENT THAT CLICKED and i don't know what is the class name!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 jQuery(jQuery('[id="frame"]')[0].contentWindow.document.body).on('click', '*', function() {
   console.log("triggered !!");
   console.log(this.className); // class of element clicked
 });
```

Comment: My bad, I had your wrapper id not the frame id from your markup

Comment: It worked but i've a problem.this code return THIS element class with PARENT class name.I need a this like "(e.target).classname".do you have an idea?

Comment: I changed it to worked for me:  =====>  
            jQuery(jQuery('[id="frame"]')[0].contentWindow.document.body).on('click', function (e) {
                var s = ($(e.target).parent().attr('class').split(" "));

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var frm = $("#frame").get(0);
    var doc = (frm.contentDocument ? frm.contentDocument : frm.contentWindow.document); //here is your document object
    var bdy = doc.body;
    $(bdy).on("click", "*", function (e) {
        console.log($(e.target).attr("class"));//To get class name
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks @John R, your code have same problem that return all class ,not this!

Comment: Can you try like this `e.target.className`?

Comment: I tried it,but it have previews problem.I edit the Mark Schultheiss' solution and it worked fine.
thank you so much for your help too.

Comment: Okay. Can you tell the edit what you made, on the comment section of Mark Schultheiss's solution?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is having problems with these solutions, I was able to make it work with John R solution, but instead of using $(document).ready I had to listen to the iframe load.

Like this:

```
$("#frame").on('load', function(){
   var frm = $("#frame").get(0);
   var doc = (frm.contentDocument ? frm.contentDocument : frm.contentWindow.document); //here is your document object
   var bdy = doc.body;

   $(bdy).on("click", "*", function (e) {
       console.log($(e.target).attr("class"));//To get class name
   });
});
```