# Twitter Video Embed auto play

Tags: twitter

I have looked through certain resources on the stack over flows but some doesn't have answer nor they are inactive.

I will want to autoplay a twitter video when some arrives on my website.

Currently It looks like this:
[image]

I was able to do Youtube, so believe this should be possible also?

Comment: What exactly is your programming problem? What have you tried?

Comment: @Lundin I am using the embedded code provided by twitter. I am not sure, how to make the video code provided by twitter auto play.

Answer (score 4):

### Note: The solution below does not work anymore out of the box due to new CORS policies of the browsers.

The twitter widget script seems to inject the player after clicking the image into an `iframe`, but the link to click is... embedded in an `iframe`. So when you see on your screen the "player" to click, it is in fact not the player but just a link to activate the injection of the player.

So your goal is to activate this injection by the following steps:

1. set up a target listener for the widget factory
2. get the widget element, once it's added to the DOM (but after it has been altered by the widget factory)
3. get it's iframe document's link that triggers the embedding of the player

### Set up Twitter for websites

Prepare your page according to the [following documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/loading):

```html
<div id="videoTarget"></div>

<!--<script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>-->
<script>
    window.twttr = (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
            t = window.twttr || {};
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return t;
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

        t._e = [];
        t.ready = function(f) {
            t._e.push(f);
        };

        return t;
    }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));

</script>
```

Our factory target will be the `videoTarget`. This is the place, where the iframe with the video injection link will be placed.

### Create the embed link

First wait for the `twttr` to be ready. Read more in this in the [scripting events](https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/events).

Then use the [factory function](https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-video/javascript-create) to create your video.

Once it's loaded, you can use jQuery to find the `iframe` content's link, that triggers the injection.

Code:

```js
window.twttr.ready(function(_twttr) {
    _twttr.widgets.createVideo(
            '560070183650213889',
            $('#videoTarget').get(0), {
                lang: "en",
            }
        )
        .then(function(el) {
            const dataId = $(el).attr('data-tweet-id');
            const doc = $('iframe').get(0).contentWindow.document;
            const link = $(doc).find("a[href*=" + dataId + "]")[0];
            link.click();
        });
});
```

Working solution: https://jsfiddle.net/5qmh1Lpn/121/

### Summary

Twitters video embed lacks of proper ways to do autoplay. However, it is IMHO an antifeature and it should be the user's decision, wether to play a video or not.

The solution is only a hack and may not work on all browsers in all situations.

Please create a fork, if you want to extend the fiddle to your needs.

**Edit:** Just for your interest, I found a hidden link with cookie consent in this code, which basically breaks down to "if you click this you agree to our policies" which is very strange, since nobody can't see this message as it's hidden.

### Thanks to:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2893315/3098783

https://stackoverflow.com/a/303961/3098783

Comment: Tried your solution but I am getting this error: Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://xxxxxx.repl.co" from accessing a cross-origin frame on the line $('iframe').get(0).contentWindow.document. Does it still work ?

Comment: True, does not work anymore due to CORS policy. I will update my answer.

Comment: A shame, was pretty clever :)